# Lazy Loading navigation properties returns 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0

I've been migrating a VB.net application using EF6 to a C# .Net Core app using EF-Core 3.0. I've always been using EF as DB-First. With EF-Core, I need to specify the way I want to load my values. Because I often need to access many navigation properties (links to other table through FKs), I'd rather to a Lazy Load than managing Eager Loads. But whenever I wanna do so, i get this error on the naviguation properties :

`((Castle.Proxies.WillyDemandesProxy)willyDemandes).IdPartNavigation
threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' : 
Error generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.LazyLoadOnDisposedContextWarning: An attempt was made to lazy-load navigation property 'IdPartNavigation' on entity type 'WillyDemandesProxy' after the associated DbContext was disposed.'. This exception can be suppressed or logged by passing event ID 'CoreEventId.LazyLoadOnDisposedContextWarning' to the 'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or 'AddDbContext'.`

Table **WillyDemandes** is linked by foreign key to table **Parts** using **WillyDemande.Id_Part** and **Parts.ID**.

When you scaffold your DbContext using EF-Core DB-First, it creates virtual properties called "**Navigation Properties**" in order for you to easily get access to the linked info in other tables.

The exception is thrown whenever you try to access IDPartNavigation. Here's an example :

[image: Navigation Property Error]

It also happens not 100% of the time.

Any ideas?

**Context**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="optionsBuilder"></param>
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
            //optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Default(WarningBehavior.Ignore));
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=TRBSQL02;Database=Info_Indus;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
    }
```

**Function**

```
    static public WillyDemandes GetFirst()
    {

        using (Info_IndusContext conn = new Info_IndusContext())
        {
            WillyDemandes willyDemandes;

                willyDemandes = conn.WillyDemandes
                    .Where(x => x.Statut == Statuts.EnTest.ToString() && x.Username == Environment.UserName)
                    //.Include(x=>x.IdPartNavigation)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Priority)
                    .ThenBy(x => x.Id)
                    .FirstOrDefault();


            if (willyDemandes != null)
            {
                willyDemandes.Statut = Statuts.EnTraitement.ToString();
                willyDemandes.ServerName = Environment.MachineName;
                willyDemandes.DateDebut = DateTime.Now;
                conn.SaveChanges();
                conn.Entry(willyDemandes).GetDatabaseValues();
                conn.Entry(willyDemandes).Reload();
            }

            return willyDemandes;
        }
    }
```

**Previously in Vb.Net**

```
Public Function Demande_GetFirst() As WillyDemandes

        Dim conn As New Info_IndusEntities(False)

        Dim DemandeWilly As WillyDemandes = conn.WillyDemandes.Where(Function(x) x.Statut = Statuts.EnTest.ToString AndAlso x.Username = Environment.UserName).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Priority).ThenBy(Function(x) x.ID).FirstOrDefault

        If Not IsNothing(DemandeWilly) Then
            DemandeWilly.Statut = Statuts.EnTraitement.ToString
            DemandeWilly.ServerName = Environment.MachineName
            DemandeWilly.DateDebut = DateTime.Now
            conn.SaveChanges()
        End If

        Return DemandeWilly

    End Function
```

### 05/21/2019

The error seems to be related to the range of DbContext. It happens when you combine **USING** and **PROXIES**.

I've written another definition of my function but this time passing the connection through parameters instead of creating it inside the function with **USING**. The proxies are then available wherever DbContext is alive.

```
    static public WillyDemandes GetFirst(Info_IndusContext conn)
{


    WillyDemandes willyDemandes;


        willyDemandes = conn.WillyDemandes
            .Where(x => x.Statut == Statuts.EnTest.ToString() && x.Username == Environment.UserName)
            //.Include(x=>x.IdPartNavigation)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Priority)
            .ThenBy(x => x.Id)
            .FirstOrDefault();

    if (willyDemandes != null)
    {
        willyDemandes.Statut = Statuts.EnTraitement.ToString();
        willyDemandes.ServerName = Environment.MachineName;
        willyDemandes.DateDebut = DateTime.Now;
        conn.SaveChanges();
        conn.Entry(willyDemandes).GetDatabaseValues();
        conn.Entry(willyDemandes).Reload();
    }

    return willyDemandes;

}
```

Comment: EF 3 is still in preview; expect bugs like this. You better report it there, accompanied with runnable code that reproduces the bug.

Comment: I tried rolling back to EF 2.2.4 but error was still there.

Comment: Well, which line throws the exception and what is `IdPartNavigation`? You better show the relevant classes.

Comment: @GertArnold I've edited the original post. It is hard to understand to someone that has never done such a thing. But i'm just hoping someday someone stumble on this post with some kind of answer.

Comment: After your edits - now it's clear that you're getting a very common exception related to triggering lazy loading after the context was disposed. That's something you should always avoid, with or without `using`. IMO, it's better to disable lazy loading and fetch data when necessary using a new context.

Comment: @GertArnold It probably is better but in that case Lazy Loading because irrelevent which is a shame because this would work perfectly in VB.Net using EF 6.0. I don't like the fact that my code will be alot more verbose in C# than in VB.net.

Comment: It's independent of language. I think in VB you didn't use the `using` statement. The problem is that you're both converting your code to C#, *and* changing the platform *and* changing the context life cycle. Try to untangle these steps. It would be much easier to convert the existing VB code to C# *ceteris paribus*.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes but like previously mentionned, I'm coming from Vb.Net (.Net Framework) with EF6.0 to C# (.net Core) with EF-Core. I think the problem is between what EF6 does versus EF-Core. But i'll take the comment and try to deal with it. The thing is I don't know yet how to create only 1 context that I could use everywhere. I guess i would need to use a Controller (Static Class) with a DbContext Property.

Comment: I know, but the best approach would have been to convert to C# using EF6 and the same .Net version. Then convert to .Net core. Then change the architecture. It's easier to track the cause of any emerging issues if you limit the moving parts. Using a static context is never recommended BTW, not even in a rich client application (which I assume this is). The more common pattern is context per window/module -- or whichever major UI elements the application has.

Comment: The problem isnt VB.net vs C# vs EF 6.. The problem is the using statement. The using will dispose of the context, and once its out of scope and you try to access it - you'll get this exception. The exception message is fairly clear about what the problem is..

Comment: How would you proceed then when you want to Lazy Load an Entity and access the naviguation properties everywhere it is passed?

Comment: @MichaëlCorriveau-Côté *do* you need to lazily load those properties to begin with? Why not eagerly load what you need? Or use a `Select` clause to only load the fields you want?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way to get through this but I ***doubt it is the best of solutions***.

Basically what I've done is that I've created a **ContextProvider** Class that allows me to create 1 **Info_IndusContext** accessible by everybody. I also removed all the *USING* statements of my controllers.

I've also abadonned using **LazyLoading** and started using **EagerLoading** as you may noticed in the GetFirst function down below.

Thoughts?

### ContextProvider

```
using WillyServer.Models;
namespace WillyServer.Controllers
{
    public static class ContextProvider
    {
        public static Info_IndusContext db = new Info_IndusContext();
    }
}
```

### WillyDemandesController.GetFirst

```
    static public WillyDemandes GetFirst()
    {

   WillyDemandes willyDemandes = ContextProvider.db.WillyDemandes
                .Include(x => x.IdPartNavigation)
                .Include(x => x.WillyMachines)
                .Where(x => x.Statut == Statuts.EnTest.ToString() && x.Username == Environment.UserName)
                .OrderBy(x => x.Priority)
                .ThenBy(x => x.Id)
                .FirstOrDefault();

        if (willyDemandes != null)
        {
            willyDemandes.Statut = Statuts.EnTraitement.ToString();
            willyDemandes.ServerName = Environment.MachineName;
            willyDemandes.DateDebut = DateTime.Now;
            ContextProvider.db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return willyDemandes;

    }
```

Comment: What you describe is the same in C# and VB.NET, Core or non-Core, and for any EF version. You *can't* use lazy loading if the context is disposed. Contexts, just like database connections are short lived and should be disposed as soon as possible, *especially* in web applications. The only reason you wouldn't get this error in VB.NET would be if the dcontext wasn't getting disposed. It's the same for other ORMs, too. Keeping a DbContext or Session alive is a bad idea as they keep track for more and more objects as time goes by

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Okay! I'm thinking of another solution that might be better than this one then!